# Observing NSUserDefaultsController not working when bound properties are set

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, imagekit, ikimagebrowserview

Here's the setup: I have a subclass of IKImageBrowserView whose `zoomValue` property is bound to a key `VFBrowserZoomValue` in the shared `NSUserDefaultsController`.  I have an `NSSlider` whose `value` binding is bound to the same key.

This works perfectly to change the `zoomValue` of the browser from the slider.

I'm trying to implement `-magnifyWithEvent:` in my `IKImageBrowserView` subclass to allow zooming the browser with the pinch gesture on trackpads.

Here's my implementation:

```
-(void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
  if ([event magnification] > 0) {
    if ([self zoomValue] < 1) {
      [self setZoomValue: [self zoomValue] + [event magnification]];
    }
  } 
  else if ([event magnification] < 0) {
    if ([self zoomValue] + [event magnification] > 0.1) {
      [self setZoomValue: [self zoomValue] + [event magnification]];
    }
    else {
      [self setZoomValue: 0.1];
    }
  }
}
```

This changes the browser's `zoomValue` correctly. The problem is that the `NSUserDefaults` is not updated with the new value.

Elsewhere in the app, I have an implementation of `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` that observes the browser's `zoomValue`.  If I log the values of the browser's zoom, the slider's value and the key in defaults in that method, I see that the browser's zoomValue has not been pushed into NSUserDefaults and the slider hasn't updated.

I've tried surrounding the `-magnifyWithEvent:` method with calls to `-{will,did}ChangeValueForKey` to no effect.

Comment: If you create an observer of the browser's zoomValue with NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld as options, does the change dictionary passed to observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: contain the correct NSKeyValueChangeNewKey and NSKeyValueChangeOldKey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The KVO flow for bindings isn't orthogonal; a binding isn't a *property*, it's a *reference* to a property.  This is the shorthand to remember for how bindings work:

- KVO is used to communicate changes from model to controller & view.
- KVC is used to communicate changes from view to controller & model.

Thus when a view with bindings handles events, it needs to propagate changes to the properties its bindings reference itself.

Here's what your code might look like, with a utility method for doing the heavy lifting of propagating changes through bindings:

```
- (void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
  if ([event magnification] > 0) {
    if ([self zoomValue] < 1) {
      [self setZoomValue: [self zoomValue] + [event magnification]];
    }
  } 
  else if ([event magnification] < 0) {
    if ([self zoomValue] + [event magnification] > 0.1) {
      [self setZoomValue: [self zoomValue] + [event magnification]];
    }
    else {
      [self setZoomValue: 0.1];
    }
  }

  // Update whatever is bound to our zoom value.
  [self updateValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self zoomValue]]
         forBinding:@"zoomValue"];
}
```

It's a little unfortunate that ImageKit requires the use of `@"zoomValue"` to reference the Zoom Value binding of an IKImageBrowserView, most bindings in AppKit have their own global string constant like `NSContentBinding`.

And here's that generic utility method to propagate the change through the binding:

```
- (void)updateValue:(id)value forBinding:(NSString *)binding
{
  NSDictionary *bindingInfo = [self infoForBinding:binding];

  if (bindingInfo) {
    NSObject *object = [bindingInfo objectForKey:NSObservedObjectKey];
    NSString *keyPath = [bindingInfo objectForKey:NSObservedKeyPathKey];
    NSDictionary *options = [bindingInfo objectForKey:NSOptionsKey];

    // Use options to apply value transformer, placeholder, etc. to value
    id transformedValue = value; // exercise for the reader

    // Tell the model or controller object the new value
    [object setValue:transformedValue forKeyPath:keyPath];
  }
}
```

Actually applying placeholders, value transformers, and the like is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's the expected behavior, see [this FAQ section](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002148-182467) of the binding documentation. You need to push that manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating a bindings-compatible control (or, in your case, subclassing one), it's up to the control to notify the controller when its value changes. So, what you'll want to do is override

```
- (void)bind:(NSString *)binding toObject:(id)observableController withKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

and keep an eye out for the binding you're interested in. Keep track of `observableController` and `keyPath` (as well as the `options` dictionary if any value transformers will be used). When you update your control's value, you'll need to send

```
[observableController setValue:newValue forKeyPath:keyPath];
```

to update the controller with the new value. Key value observing is a one-way street, and in bindings the controls are the observers.